How to remove all HTML or XML tags with regex?
How to remove all HTML or XML tags from a file with Vim regex?
:%s/<.*>//g

is greedy and will match everything between the first < and the last > on the line.

Related: Why is it such a bad idea to parse XML with regex?

And the infamous StackOverflow question

.* is indeed too greedy but it is not the . that makes it greedy, it is the *, and using [^>] instead of . doesn't make your pattern less greedy. You would need to use a different quantifier for that:
:%s/<.\{-}>//g

That said, this method (with your pattern or mine) may work on simple HTML but I just tried it on this very page to compare the outputs and it left quite a few HTML tags behind, so it is far from optimal.
Beside, handling HTML with regular expressions is a recipe for disaster.
Here is a more sensible approach:
:%!pandoc --to=plain


Nice solution provided you have pandoc installed of course
What are the limitations of our the naive regex solutions ? How come it left tags behind ?

Installing stuff like pandoc, jq, etc. is easy. Unix is beautiful.

@cassepipe have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?

In other words, regular expressions are not a good fit for that specific problem, therefore relying on them for anything vaguely complex is a bad idea.

@D.BenKnoble No I did not see it. I am not sure what it is the general policy about it around here but I personally like that some answers that are scattered on overflow or unix are duplicated here even if only to link to them so I  only tried google at first and then vi.stackexchange search bar

:%s/<[^>]*>//g

The solution works because [^>]* matches any character except >
